# Understanding THE_REQUEST variable in RewriteCond

Tags: regex, apache, mod-rewrite

`RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(.+)\.php([#?][^\ ]*)?\ HTTP/`

I understand everything in the line above except for the following segment:

`([#?][^\ ]*)?\ HTTP/`

I've done some research and found out that the square brackets are used to match any one of the characters within them. However, I have also learned that `?` is used to make the preceding token optional and that `^` means "match start."

As such, why do the square brackets in the segment above contain both `?` and `^`? I thought that the square brackets were simply used as a "character class."

Also, what is the purpose of `HTTP/` in the segment specifically? All of my searches have come to no avail.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First understand what is `THE_REQUEST`.

`THE_REQUEST` variable represents original request received by Apache from your browser and it doesn't get overwritten after execution of some rewrite rules. Example value of this variable is:

```
GET /index.php?id=123 HTTP/1.1
```

Now the part you want more clarification on:

```
([#?][^\ ]*)?\ HTTP/
```

Here is what is happening here:

1. It matches `?` or `#` literally since inside `[...]` almost all special characters are matched literally
2. Followed by a negated character class that matches 0 or more characters of anything except a space
3. `?` after `([#?][^\ ]*)` makes it an optional match
4. `\ HTTP` matches a space followed by `HTTP`

**Now let me tell you that matching `#` is not needed here** since a web server never receives a URL after `#`. That is all handled by client browsers.

It is better to use this `RewriteCond`:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(.+)\.php(\?\S*)?\ HTTP/ [NC]
```