# After the redirect I get the page: Site 'xxx' has redirected too many times

Tags: php, .htaccess, modx

This is essentially the same page, I just need to redirect from a url that uses the GET parameter to a url without this parameter.

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^category=([^&]+)&key=news-category$
RewriteRule ^news/$ /news/%1/? [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Open your browser's debug tools (usually by pressing F12), go to the Network tab, and load the page. That will show you the sequence of redirects that happens before the browser gives up. Either the page is redirecting back to the same URL, or two redirects are conflicting with each other and it's bouncing back and forth; but without knowing which, neither you nor anyone else can get very far.

Comment: The `?` at the end of the substitution URL should make it not have any query string any more, so on the next request your RewriteCond should not be true any more. Most likely the new URL gets rewritten again, by some other part of your rewrite setup.

Comment: You are right, the page redirects to itself. Is it possible to solve this problem?

Comment: You probably have a rule, that internally rewrites `/news/foobar` to `news/?category=foobar&key=news-category` again, I suppose? Then you'll need to use a RewriteCond that checks on the original `THE_REQUEST` value. https://stackoverflow.com/q/44993370/1427878

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^category=([^&]+)&key=news-category$
> RewriteRule ^news/$ /news/%1/? [R=301,L]
> ```

This rule should only apply to direct requests from the client, not rewritten requests (by other rules) - which is probably what's causing the redirect loop. You need an additional *condition* (`RewriteCond` directive) on the above rule. For example:

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
:
```

This rule should also appear early on in the `.htaccess` file, before other *rewrites*.

The `REDIRECT_STATUS` environment variable is empty on the initial request and set to `200` (as in "200 OK" HTTP status) after the later rewrite.

Also, if you are on Apache 2.4, consider using the `QSD` (Query String Discard) instead of appending an empty query string (in order to *remove* the original query string). The `QSD` flag completely removes the query string, whereas the trailing `?` sets an empty query string which relies on the user-agent (browser) removing the trailing `?` in the redirected request.

Clear your browser cache before testing and test with 302 (temp) redirects to avoid potential caching issues.

*Aside:* Make sure you are linking directly to the "pretty" URL. This "redirect" directive should not be processed at all under normal conditions (it's only required to preserve SEO when *changing* an existing URL structure).